# gnome terminal scrollbar visibility

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, scrollbar

According the manual below

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-scrolling.html.en

There is an option (`Edit ▸ Profile Preferences ▸ Scrolling`) "Scrollbar visibility" so that you can choose from the following options:

```
Always visible: Scrollbar is visible at all times.

Visible only when necessary: Scrollbar is visible only when terminal output exceeds the length of Terminal window size.

Hidden: Scrollbar is always hidden from view.
```

But in Ubuntu 12.04 (I removed unity so the scrollbar is the old style), there is no such option. The scrollbar is always shown even I didn't type anything.

How to change this, please.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to follow instructions a bit carefully.
Look and see, please:
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Could you expand a little bit what you mean by 'follow instructions'?

Comment: @Alioth -1: he clearly meant the option to show the scrollbar only when necessary.